# Singleton or Service for socket connection

Tags: android, service, websocket

I'm new to Android development, i'm trying to port an IOS app to Android. Basically my App need to communicate with a server in real time with socket IO. It connect to the server and then handle the various message until the server finish to process the request.

In my IOS app i use a Singleton pattern to send the requests to my websocket server, and i use the same instance to delegate the server response.
In Android i was going to use the same pattern, with a callback object in my activity to redirect the user after getting a server response.

I need my app to keep the socket connection open until we got the right status from the server, even if the app goes in background.

Some people recommend using Service with Broadcast receiver instead of Singleton. Is it the best thing to do in my case ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using a `Service` is exactly what I have done for very similar purposes (doing socket communication for Bluetooth and TCP/IP applications) and think you'll certainly want to be using a `Service` if the communication should continue even when the user has closed the application.

A `Service` is essentially a means to run code on the UI thread (but of course you can then start off other threads within it) but without a user interface, unlike an `Activity` which has a UI associated with it.

If you were to try to do this in a static singleton class as you propose as an alternative, then I think the problem would be that you wouldn't have very good control over the lifecycle of it. If the user navigates away from the application, then my understanding is that it's up to the framework when it chooses to remove the process and all the static objects along with it. For this reason, if you have singleton classes populated with data and you exit your application and then later come back to the application, you may or may not find that the 'old' singleton instances are still around. For this reason, in my application (which uses a very large amount of global state) I've resorted to holding my singletons' actual instances in an extension of the `.Application` class, to (hopefully) better control their lifecycle.

With a `Service` you have a well-defined lifecycle with appropriate lifecycle callbacks (`onCreate()`, `onDestroy()`, etc.) just as you do with an `Activity`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer Trevor Page ! Ok i'm going with a service with another thread to implement that. But how can i make my Service and my Activities communicate to each other the various request state update. The activity could create a request through socket Io and the Service need to communicate the status update to the various activities. Does i need to implement a Broadcast for each component ?

Comment: Ok i found that i need to bind my service with my activities in order to interact with it. But i'm still confused on the method i could use in order to get the Service (the socket connection) results in my activity ?

Comment: Ok if figured out how to communicate between my Service and my Activity both ways. I need to use an IBinder for calling the service from my Activity and the i need to use a BroadcastReceiver for getting the server results in my activity, hope it could help someone.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, definitely use a `Service`. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html):

> A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user

While using a singleton might work for a while, your application would be prone to being killed by the operating system when it goes into the background unless you have a `Service`. If you're more comfortable with the singleton pattern, you *could* implement it in a singleton and then just tie it to a `Service` simply to maintain its lifecycle, but that seems more of a mess than it's worth. Note that you shouldn't do network operations on the UI thread and by default a Service runs on the UI thread. You'll need to spin up another thread to do your work.

I don't see anything in your post that demands a `BroadcastReceiver`, though perhaps there may be some network related broadcast intents that might be useful like [`android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, can you look my comment on Travor Page's response for the broadcast point ?